# Most efficient way of checking positions of a list inside another list in Python

Tags: python, performance, list

This is not a questions about how to do but more about how to do it more efficiently. I have 2 lists, a superList which contains all elements from a subList and some elements more. Lets take the following lists for example:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] # a is my superList
b = [2,3,5,7] # b is my subList
```

I want to check which elements of b exists in in a in a way I got a list for and answer like:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

I have this code here the does the work well for short lists and a small amount ob subList but gets inefficient once the data size starts to increase. Which solutions would be more efficient than the solution below. Remember I want to run this code for a huge amount of checks of shortList inside a longList. It's a for nested inside a for situation:

```
def isInList(longList, shortList):
    indexList = []
    for i in range(len(longList)):
        if longList[i] in shortList:
            indexList.append(1)
        else:
            indexList.append(0)
    return indexList
```

Comment: The performance is O(nm) where n is the size of a and m is the size of b. You can get a O(n) solution if you make shortlist a `set`

Comment: Syntax-wise, you can just do `for i in longList: if i in shortList:` etc.

Comment: How about list comprehensions ?

Answer (score 4):

List comprehension is very efficient in Python.  A quick way to check in O(n) is to do:

```
[1*(aa in b) for aa in a]
# returns:
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Even more efficient is to convert `b` to a set, as checking for existence in a set is of O(1).

```
b_set = set(b)
[1*(aa in b_set) for aa in a]
# return:
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: in case it's not clear what the multiplying by 1 is doing, it's casting the bool to an int. you could also do `int(aa in b)` (for OP)

Comment: on further testing, calling `int` is slower than multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can go is:

```
[1 if _ in b else 0 for _ in a]
```